# "Failed to create video camera" OpenCvSharp with C#

Tags: c#, opencv, opencv3.0

I tried to build working camera in winforms app with C# using "OpenCvSharp3" NuGet, and when I am trying: `var capture = new videoCapture(0);` it shows no red underlines, but when I am running the program it says

> "Failed to create videoCamera" .

I searched all over the internet for the problem solution but it seems like nobody else had this problem...

I tried launching it with Administrator but it seems like its not helping...

Here is the code I used to create and use the video camera:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)         {
  var Capture = new VideoCapture(0);
  Capture.Open(0);
  var frame = new Mat();
  Capture.Read(frame);
  var image = BitmapConverter.ToBitmap(frame);
  Bitmap photo = new Bitmap(image);
  pictureBox1.Image = image;
}
```

**here is the stack exeption:**

```
*System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at System.Drawing.Bitmap..ctor(Image original)
   at Cam_Troll_001.Form1.button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\Yakov\source\repos\Cam_Troll_001\Cam_Troll_001\Form1.cs:line 93
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)*
```

p.s:

Had to add that when I am running the program I can see the flash on my web-cam turning on, however the code still gives me an error saying "Failed to create video camera"

Comment: You can put more info? Like the full code method, or stack exception? Please [see](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I wasnt able to add the exeption as comment or as text in the original question so I pasted picture with it in the original post, hope it will be ok !

Comment: "I wasnt able to add the exeption as text in the original question" ...why, what did it say? Errors should be pasted as text. If you're having a problem with that, do what the editor tells you to do e.g. add more context, or format it properly or whatever the issue was. Don't resort to pictures - they're not searchable, or pasteable, for a start. Same with your code - don't add it to the comments, add it to the question properly. Since you did provide the code as text in your comment, I edited it into the question for you, but I can't do that with your picture. Thanks.

Comment: Ok thank you, I did it that way. 
I am new to stack overflow so thank you for helping me.